# Can't execute mouse hover using Actions class in Selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, mouseover

I'm trying to open Apps panel using Actions class which is partially hidden. First I need mouse hover on and then click on it.

Please see the screenshots to understand what kind of element I'm talking about.

[Apps panel before hoover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AFi0i.png),  [Apps panel after mouse hoover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cs2zB.png),  [html code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKaEe.png).

I'm getting following error when doing this code:

A)

```
public void getAppsPanel() {
        Actions act = new Actions(getDriver());
        WebElement appsPanelIcon = getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Apps Panel')]"));
        act.moveToElement(appsPanelIcon).perform();
        appsPanelIcon.click();
    }
```

B)

```
public void getAppsPanel() {
    Actions act = new Actions(getDriver());
    WebElement appsPanelIcon = getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Apps Panel')]"));
    act.moveToElement(appsPanelIcon, 30, 30).perform();
    appsPanelIcon.click();
}
```

Mar 16, 2021 2:36:54 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C

org.openqa.selenium.interactions.MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException: move target out of bounds
(Session info: headless chrome=89.0.4389.82)
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: '*****', ip: '*****', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.11.6', java.version: '15.0.1'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 89.0.4389.82, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 89.0.4389.23 (61b08ee2c5002..., userDataDir: /var/folders/0v/zqm2pp7n33n...}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:51341}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: MAC, platformName: MAC, proxy: Proxy(), setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webauthn:extension:largeBlob: true, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true}
Session ID: 987e9ee9266d17c0b3413260be25b50a

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: What happens when you debug your code and you get to the findElement? I'm not familiar with Java, but I am with C# and Python. "Out of bounds' sounds like it might be an array issue, so maybe it's returning more than one element with the same Xpath. Try FindElements and see if it returns an array of elements.

Comment: Hi, thank you for you recommendation! the problem was I tried to hover element which is hidden. So I used wrong xpath. I took xpath of visible part of control. Here is the working code: public class ContactsPage extends GenericPageObject{
    @FindBy(xpath = "//*[contains(@class, 'jss251')]")
    WebElement appsPanelIcon;
    @FindBy(xpath = "//*[contains(text(),'Apps Panel')]")
    WebElement appsPanelButton;

    public void getAppsPanel() {
        Actions act = new Actions(getDriver());
        act.moveToElement(appsPanelIcon).perform();
        appsPanelButton.click();
    }